# LightGBM not found

Tags: python, macos, lightgbm

I've encountered an error when trying to use LightGBM in my Python project. Whenever I attempt to import LightGBM in my code, I get the following error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/hp/opt/anaconda3/envs/MachineLearning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
Referenced from: <3AF1EF0C-311C-31EC-BCE3-679F37ABEE16> /Users/hp/opt/anaconda3/envs/MachineLearning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib/lib_lightgbm.so
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

I'm working in a conda environment named "MachineLearning" on macOS, and I've tried setting the `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` environment variables as suggested in various sources, but the issue persists.
Can someone please help me understand what's causing this error and provide steps to resolve it? I'm stuck at this point because I'm trying to use LightGBM for Streamlit and FastAPI projects.

Environment Details:

> - Python Version: 3.9
> - Conda Environment: "MachineLearning"
> - Operating System: macOS

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default, distributions of the `lightgbm` Python package expect to be able to link to OpenMP at runtime. It appears you don't have OpenMP available at any of the standard paths that the linker will search.

Since you're already working in a `conda` environment, use `conda` / `mamba` to install `lightgbm`, not `pip install`. That way, you'll get `conda-forge`'s distribution of OpenMP automatically ([conda-forge/lightgbm-feedstock link](https://github.com/conda-forge/lightgbm-feedstock/blob/72b9a7bddd4da089ffa2c805315a323245497f53/recipe/meta.yaml#L29-L30)) and not need to worry about installing it separately.

Run the following to fix your issue:

```bash
# remove pip-installed copy of 'lightgbm' in MachineLearning conda env
source activate MachineLearning
pip uninstall --yes lightgbm

# install conda-forge distribution instead
conda install \
   --yes \
   --name MachineLearning \
   -c conda-forge \
   'lightgbm>=4.1.0'
```

With that, you should not need to make any customizations to environment variables like `LDFLAGS` and `lightgbm` should load successfully in a Python process in that `conda` environment.

If it's absolutely necessary that you use `pip install lightgbm` or build `lightgbm` from source (e.g. to customize the build or to use unreleased versions), then install OpenMP separately in that conda environment:

```bash
conda install \
   --yes \
   --name MachineLearning \
   -c conda-forge \
   llvm-openmp
```

Answer (score -1):

The error said OpenMP library is not installed. According to [LightGBM doc](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Installation-Guide.html#macos), it is better to install LightGBM via `brew install lightgbm`

Comment: I already did this but it's still not working

Comment: actually, lightgbm python package install via `pip install lightgbm`.  No brew needed. Please provide full error call stack to help troubleshooting.

Comment: this answer does not address the OP's question. The question is about installing `lightgbm` (the LightGBM Python package). `brew install lightgbm` installs the `lightgbm` command-line interface (CLI).